# Creating a distribution list within CRM 2011

Tags: outlook, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, outlook-2013

I am trying to find a efficient way for our users to email multiple contacts within CRM with a custom email (no templates) on demand.

After playing around with it for a long time, I came up with the following:

1. Create a custom view under "Contacts" that holds the group you want to email.
2. Select one of the contacts, go to the "Add" tab, and select "Email"
3. Click the search box beside "To" and fill out the popup with the following:
4. Look for: "Contact"
5. View: "-The name of your custom view from step 1-"
6. Select all of the contacts in the view
7. Click "Add"
8. Click "OK"
9. Complete the email and send it

However, this is not efficient and would confuse our users.  I am looking for a better solution to email multiple users at once within CRM or to dynamically pull contacts from CRM and put them in a distribution list in Outlook 2013 (probably not even possible).

Comment: and what if users will create distibution lists based on previous one? Also, I think you can make a flag or a radio button (true/false) inside of a contact form that provide an opportunity to user change a status of a including contact to the distribution list. So, if you'd use this way you choul check a dinamic distribution list

Comment: This question shouldn't have been closed... pay closer attention Will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are sending to Contacts, Leads, or Accounts:

- Select all records on the view that has been set up for this purpose with the top left checkbox
- Click the Add Tab above the Ribbon
- Click Quick Campaign -> For All Records on All Pages
- Use the Wizard, ensuring that "Mark Email Messages to be Sent" is checked

Comment: This is a solid solution to the problem, except I cannot add attachments this way.  Any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately attachments cannot be added.